# i have added background image using a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have added a background image to a div but image is not showing up, please help me out what i am missing.
here is the code
                  **CSS:**

```
.riseImages
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
    background-image: url("img\page1\bg shapes.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: initial;
    /*-webkit-animation-name: rise;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;*/
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="riseImages topRise"></div>
<div class="riseImages bottomRise"></div>
```

i am not getting the desired output, background image is not showing up,                earlier it was working fine.

Comment: This depends not only on the code but alsso ur file structure. Cn you please post your entire code and the folder structure for yiur html, css and the image file

Comment: you can't use backslash like that, because it will be interpreted as `\p` symbol, instead of `\ ` symbol. you have to use ` \\ `

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS:

```
background-image: url("img/page1/bg shapes.png");
```

Comment: Lol! Did not notice those slashes up there.. Thanks for noticing.. But i still think the issue is something else

Comment: with the given material and my limited knowledge this is what i think problem is :) , let the OP check and come back

Answer (score 0):

change css `background-image: url("img\page1\bg shapes.png");`

please add this method `Forward slash: /`

like Css `background-image: url("img/page1/bg shapes.png");`

or

try

Basically given:

```
background-image: url("../img/page1/bg shapes.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image: url("img\page1\bg shapes.png");` what is bg
is it your folder or image name? avoid that space from in it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is space in Image name.

Try Renaming Image as `bg_shapes.png` 
Then use it with `background-image: url("/img/page1/bg_shapes.png");`